# Error while trying to save data into hdfs

Tags: pandas, kubernetes, hadoop, hdfs, pandas.excelwriter

I'm trying to move data from local to hdfs using jupyter after the Data cleaning, i found some issues while doing it, and the data won't move into hdfs ( hdfs & jupyter deployed in minikube k8s)

This is the code in jupyter :

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("data.xlsx")
data.to_excel( excel_writer=writer)
writer.save("hdfs://hdfs-namenode-0.hdfs-namenode.default.svc.cluster.local/data")
```

The error is  :

```
save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Forgetting to specify the self argument in a class method.
Forgetting to specify a second argument in a function's definition.
Passing two arguments to a function that only takes one.
Overriding a built-in function by mistake.

Comment: Last I checked, pandas cannot write to HDFS, and generally, Excel files shouldn't be stored in HDFS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how i solved my problem :

```
Client = InsecureClient('http://hdfs-namenode.default.svc.cluster.local:50070', user='hdfs')
data = pd.read_csv('name_of_file.csv')
with client.upload('path/name_of_file.csv' , 'name_of_file.csv', n_threads=1, temp_dir=None) as writer : 
    data.to_csv(writer)
```

Comment: Why do you need pandas at all? Just upload the file without reading to a dataframe since you're not doing anything with it here